# Remove dot from textbox on text input

Tags: javascript

How can I remove/disallow entering a dot `.` on my textbox?

Comment: Why don't you allow the dots on the input and delete them on your back code? That's much more user friendly.

Comment: Sure, but this is what I want it to do

Comment: On your server code, i mean. Allow entering dots, and when you submit the form, you do a replace(".", "") or something like that.

Comment: Because it is saved on the DB and i want it without dots

Comment: Remove the dots before saving to the db.

Comment: @ariel - Removing at the backend is user UNfriendly, assuming you mean to just silently swallow the dots without telling the user. Users have a quite reasonable expectation that what they type is what will be stored, and if not they should get some kind of validation error message (whether from the backend or frontend).

Comment: @nnnnnn Im sure the user gets more puzzled when his "." key don't work than the way what he typed is stored on the DB. Worst: Give the user an error and ask him to remove the ".". Good: Don't accept ".". Best: Accept whatever he types and handle it later.

Comment: @ariel Disagree. It's far better to disallow the `.` client-side than to silently drop it server-side. You're also dead wrong: **Best** by far is telling the user that the field may not contain `.`, and asking them to remove it, ideally before posting back to the server. **Worst** is trying to accept whatever the user types and "handle it later". That is just absolutely awful design and a massive violation of [POLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). What do you do if the user has entered only dots, save a `null` to the database?

Comment: @meagar sorry but i just assumed he want to remove dots from number or document number entry. and for me dot is thousand separator, like commas in US. in the case of preventing a thousand separator being typed in, i believe the best is to accept and remove/reformat them later. for other uses i agree with you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bind an event to your `input` tag

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return preventDot(event);" />
```

Then create a function like `preventDot` that will `return false` and prevent the key from being entered if the `.` key is pressed

```
function preventDot(e)
{
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;

    if (key == 46)
    {
        return false;
    }    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bf6Xq/6/

Comment: Hi thanks for your code but what I want is the dot to be removed as soon as it is typed.

Comment: that does do that. Did you click the link?

Comment: Well, yes. I type for example abcde.fgh but the . is still there

Comment: Working of chrome but not in firefox

Comment: or just use jquery and talk to all browsers with the same code ;)

Comment: This is a perfect solution here... +1

Comment: @ariel, even jQuery doesn't handle this well `(e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);`

Comment: @ariel - "event.which seems to be allways "undefined" in internet explorer 9."

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

JavaScript:

```
function preventDot(id)
{
    str = document.getElementById(id).value;
    document.getElementById(id).value = (str.replace(".",""));  
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="preventDot(this.id)" />
```